# Turn off VS Code red highlight

Tags: visual-studio-code, highlighting

I ran across this highlight sometimes, and it is really a PITA. This is it:

[image: VS Code red highlight]

It doesn't seem to have any meaning to me, just a block of red. It extends to all the lines after that too, and only goes away when I delete the line.

What is it, and how can I turn it off?

Comment: This seems like it would be more understandable with more context (e.g. at least a full line). Most likely meant to highlight an error.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I was able to turn this off after clearing out my ctrl+f search box. I used it to search my code previously for a particular word and never cleared it out so all instances of that word moving forward were highlighted red...hope this helps, just clear out your ctrl+f input box.